# Detect which anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have many a tags like this

```
<a href="javascript:changeFreq()">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="javascript:changeFreq()">Anchor 2</a>
<a href="javascript:changeFreq()">Anchor 3</a>
```

How to indentify which a is clicked in `changeFreq` function.
I tried to use `this` pointer but it refers `window` object.
I can't use `onclick` event in this context

Any idea?

Comment: How about `href="#" onclick="changeFreq()"`? This should probably give you a proper this reference.

Comment: Easy way would be to give the `<a>` their own Ids so you can reference that.

Comment: Situation is so that I can edit anchors, only changeFreq function,

Answer (score 4):

Use proper event handlers.
The markup

```
<a href="#" class="anchor">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">Anchor 2</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">Anchor 3</a>
```

with

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.anchor');

for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}

function handler() {

    // now "this" is the element

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7e7k/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with only one event listener.  The idea is only attach one listener and then delegate what to do depending on what was clicked on.  This way you don't have a ton of listeners to do the job that one could handle.  With this problem, it might be overkill to do, but I did want to provide an alternative.

**<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zero298/S9rU5/)</kbd>**

**HTML**

```
<!--
Parent div to have the actual listener. 
Whenever an anchor is clicked, the event will bubble up to the #wrap div
-->
<div id="wrap">
   <!--Each div has a data-freq attribute to pass it's frequency-->
   <a id="a1" href="#" data-freq="1">Anchor 1</a><br>
   <a id="a2" href="#" data-freq="10">Anchor 2</a><br>
   <a id="a3" href="#" data-freq="100">Anchor 3</a><br>
</div>
<!--Print out the frequency-->
<div>Frequency: </div>
<div id="freq">0</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Get the important elements
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap"),
        freqDiv = document.getElementById("freq");

// Function to let us change frequency
function changeFrequency(amount) {
   freqDiv.innerHTML = amount;
}

// Add only one event listener and let clicks bubble up
wrap.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   // Change the frequency by the data-freq value
   changeFrequency(e.target.dataset["freq"]);
   // Don't change pages
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use `this` in the `onclick` tag   it will pass the `a` tag reference into your function.

http://jsfiddle.net/V3W38/
e.g.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return changeFreq(this)">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return changeFreq(this)">Anchor 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return changeFreq(this)">Anchor 3</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeFreq(element)
{
    // this is reference to the a tag you clicked on
    console.log(element.href);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I know event handling is better, but this is simpler if you just want to do simple stuff

Answer (score 0):

Did you jsut try to add an input variable in your function?

```
<a href="javascript:changeFreq(1)">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="javascript:changeFreq(2)">Anchor 2</a>
<a href="javascript:changeFreq(3)">Anchor 3</a>
```

js:

```
function changeFreq(anchorId){
     switch(anchorId){
         case 1:
         ///...
         break;
         //...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7e7k/1/)

if a anchor tag is clicked that anchor tags href or id is returned which is displayed in alert You can you this as you like

### Jquery

```
$( "a" ).click( handler ).find( "a" );
function handler( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  
  if ( target.is( "a" ) ) {
    alert(target.html());
        alert(target.attr("href"));
      alert(target.attr("id"));
  }
}
```

### CSS

```
<a href="javascript:changeFreq(this)">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="javascript:changeFreq(this)">Anchor 2</a>
<a id="i1" href="javascript:changeFreq(this)">Anchor 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event listener by using jQuery. In my case i get the attribute href and target and perform some actions. You can use what ever you want there.

```
jQuery('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var target = jQuery(this).attr('target');
    if (target === '_blank') {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    } else {
        window.open(url, '_self');
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.